# Is there a way to develop web pages with autorefresh, like Ionic Serve do it?

Tags: ionic-framework

after I discovered **ionic serve** I am really curious if there is a way to use this technologie for normal web page development? I know that you can make

I want my page to refresh itselves after I change js or css files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/). Here's the [official howto](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/67441-how-do-i-start-using-livereload).